# Tertium non datur and Inductive Subset of a Well Ordered Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Theorem:

*Let (S,⪯)  be a well-ordered set. 
Let T⊆S  be an inductive subset of S, that is such that:

∀s∈S:(∀t∈S:t≺s⟹t∈T)⟹s∈T (induction hypothesis)
Then T=S.*

Using reductio ad absurdum the proof is very simple.  If S\T is nonempty, then it has a lowest element x, which satisfies the induction hypothesis.  As such x∈T, contradiction, q.e.d.

My question is whether *tertium non datur/reductio ad absurdum* can be avoided in this proof.

Comment: pinky promise: this is my last question on foundations of elementary set theory for 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you're proving the contrapositive: if $T\subsetneq S$ then $T$ is not inductive. Suppose $T\subsetneq S$. Then $S\setminus T\ne \emptyset$, so it has a least element $x$. For any $s\in S$, if $s<x$ then $s\in T$ by definition of $x$; however, $x\notin T$. Therefore,
$$
\exists s\in S\,((\forall t\in S\,(t<s\to t\in T) \land s\notin T),
$$
which says "T is not inductive".

Comment: So you switch the argument around, showing that ANY proper subset of a w.o. set is not inductive.  As the whole set is inductive, and is a subset of itself it follows that the only inductive subset of a w.o. set is the set itself. Thank you

Comment: Exactly. (& you're welcome) I too usually start to wonder if I read or write a proof of $p$ that starts by assuming $\neg p$ and deduces $p$. (It works because $(\neg p\to p)\to p)$ is valid in classical logic, but it's basically law of excluded middle using $\to$ and $\neg$. It's not valid in intuitionistic logic; there, if $\neg p$ implies $p$, you can only conclude $\neg\neg p$, which intuitionistically is not the same as $p$). Namely, I start to wonder whether we can't just prove $p$ instead of $\neg\neg p$ :)